# how to copy only body of pdf file using itextsharp or pdfsharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, parsing, itext, pdfsharp

***I am still waiting for the reply from you all. I really need your support.......plz***

I am developing a project called pdf recovery. In that i want to just copy the body of file into another pdf file using **itextsharp C# lib**.

> i want to parse entire file as soon as i get body i.e. " 1 0 obj<<....>>endobj " according to pdf reference. then copy full body to another pdf file.

i dont to want to read header,xref table..etc.

I am using itextsharp lib for creating a file. if pdfsharp provides this i will move to that one. **Also give some tips about both lib**.
Thnx. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the page stamper (like in the example at http://1t3xt.info/examples/browse/?page=example&id=27 - this is for the Java version, but you should not have any problems adapting that to C#) it will only copy the page content, and will create a new "header" (I assume you mean the meta data) and xref table. 
Using this mechanism will copy all required resources (e.g. fonts, bitmaps, ...) automatically for you. If you would do it manually, you would have to do that too, and that gets a bit messy. 
Oh, and there is no need to parse anything. iTextSharp will do all the parsing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried asking on the Itext/ISharp mailing list?